# Populate array in Javascript with records from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, model

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. The idea is to populate this array with records from a database.

```
    var locations = [];
```

I have the following model:

```
public partial class threat
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int threat_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetJsonData()
    {
        var data = new List<threat>();
        data.Add(new threat { category_id = 0, threat_id = 0, lat = 12, lng = 12 });
        data.Add(new threat { category_id = 0, threat_id = 0, lat = 13, lng = 13 });
        data.Add(new threat { category_id = 0, threat_id = 0, lat = 14, lng = 14 });
        data.Add(new threat { category_id = 0, threat_id = 0, lat = 15, lng = 15 });

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var locations = [];

        $.getJSON("/Home/GetJsonData", null, function (data) {
            locations = data;
        });

        $("#btnShowData").click(function () {

            for(var i =0;i < locations.length;i++){
                var location = locations[i];
                var message = "Location Lat - " + location.lat + ".Location Lon - " + location.lng;
                alert(message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnShowData" value="Show Data" />
</div>
```

I'm using a static `List<T>` in the example above so just replace that logic to return data from your database and the rest will work as is.Not sure what ORM you're using but here's a simple [Entity Framework Database First example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)